# python program hangs when trying to read from the stdout from another program

Tags: python

I am trying to get my python program to parse the output of the strace command to make it more readable for debugging purposes.

However when I try to get to readline from its stdout, it just hangs there after the second time calling it, with the first time just being an empty string.

```
def openProgram():
     print ("Search for pid of progarm")
     pids = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "python"])
     pid = pids.split()[-1]
     if pid:
         print ("Pid found at " + str(pid) + "attaching to process")
         pname = "strace"
         arg = " -p " + str(pid) + " -s9999 -e write"
         proc = subprocess.Popen(pname + arg , shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
         return proc
#(some other code here)
proc = openProgram()
if proc:
    while proc.poll() is None:
         output = proc.stdout.readline() #hangs here
```

Note, the strace progarm can't end on is own, and needs to read what it is currently sending, as it is currently sending and not after strace ended.

Comment: If the other program isn't calling any system calls then strace won't print any output. And, if strace doesn't print any output, then the `proc.stdout.readline()` will correctly block.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. Please create the shortest possible program that demonstrates the error, and copy-paste the complete, short program into your question. ([Here is mine](http://ideone.com/cJszK6)). On my Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7, my version of your program correctly prints the output of `strace -V`.

Comment: I think a process must be finished before you can read its stdout

Comment: I tested this -V (mistaken put in -v, earlier) and the program can read when it ends, but not when it is currently running.